RollupError: Expected ';', '}' or <eof> (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
I am getting this error while running the build.

Below is the code index.tsx file:
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import { styles } from "./styles";
import * as React from "react";
import classNames from "classnames";

type DefaultProps = {
  /**Different variations of button component */
  variant: "primary" | "secondary";

  /**Sizes of component */
  size: "small" | "medium" | "large";
};

type Props = DefaultProps & {
  /**Button Label */
  label: string | React.ReactNode;

  /**On Click handle for button */
  onClick: (event: React.SyntheticEvent) => void;
};

function ButtonComponent(props: Props) {
  const { label, onClick, variant = "primary", size = "medium" } = props;
  const buttonClasses = classNames({
    buttonPrimary: variant === "primary",
    buttonSecondary: variant === "secondary",
  });
  return (
    <Button
      onClick={onClick}
      className={buttonClasses}
      sx={styles.buttonDefaults}
      size={size}
    >
      {label}
    </Button>
  );
}

export default ButtonComponent;

And here is the config for rollup:
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import { nodeResolve } from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import peerDepsExternalPlugin from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import { dts } from "rollup-plugin-dts";

export default [
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [
      { file: "dist/cjs/index.js", format: "cjs", sourcemap: true },
      { file: "dist/esm/index.js", format: "esm", sourcemap: true },
    ],
    plugins: [
      nodeResolve(),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" }),
      peerDepsExternalPlugin(),
    ],
    external: ["react", "react-dom"],
  },
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [{ file: "dist/types.d.ts", format: "es" }],
    plugins: [dts()],
  },
];

I tried commenting the code inside the indext.tsx and created a simple hello world return function but still there is error. I am new to rollup, these are some config I got from web. Can anybody help me fix this. If any additional details needed please ask.
